# PC Stuck at BIOS screen

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

Yesterday I tried to update the BIOS of my Asus a7v8x-la (Award-Phoenix bios) based motherboard with a custom BIOS build.
But the operation was interrupted in the middle, and the PC is now stuck at the bios screen.
I am unable to press the F2 to enter BIOS setup or Del to enter the boot menu.
Nothing happens when I press any key. I waited around 4-5 minutes, but still, it is stuck. No LEDs in keyboard are also blinking.
Could anyone tell me a solution to fix the issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you've turned your motherboard into what's commonly known as "a brick" - should never interrupt a bios / firmware update

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I recover from this?

Comment: If it will still try to boot from something (usb/hd/drive) you might be in luck... I've read that routers that have been bricked can sometimes be recovered using something like a jtag connector, not at all sure about motherboards. They used to have bios stuff on a specific chip, sometimes they were swap-able or solder on a new one... If you can exchange it under warranty that's best (if they allow "bios update failure")

Comment: Oh ok. I will check for bootable option.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to reset the bios by removing the CMOS battery.

If this doesn't work, you would need to short out the BIOS and force it to use
a backup BIOS which may be available on the BIOS chip.
But this operation is better be done by a qualified repairman.

Under extreme conditions, the BIOS chip itself may be exchanged for one that
contains a compatible version, which is better better done through your supplier
or the manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you mean by " short out the BIOS"? how can I do that?

Comment: I'm not a repair-man - all I know that you short together two pins on the BIOS chip, but I don't have any details.